# sqlldr import data,

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

there is a question need your help about SQL loader:

when using SQL loader import data,  for date field, the value is '7232012' represent 2012-07-23, in SQL loader control file , how can i write the date format?

thanks!

Comment: @Florin, doesn't work in 10g, I get "date format not recognized". Does that work in 11g?

Comment: @DCookie doesn't work. It is like you explained in the answer. Can lpad be used in ctl files? (he can append a 0 for strings with length less than 8 characters)

Comment: He could, but that's not necessarily a good solution. There are ambiguous dates, e.g., 1112012. Is it Jan 11, or Nov 1?

Comment: The oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free.  You really should learn to use it to answer trivial syntax questions such as this.  For instance, here is the chapater explaining datatypes in SQL*Loader control files: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10701/ldr_field_list.htm#i1006714

Comment: @Florin, the format string is  not be recognized,

Comment: @DCookie, the date for Day string will not lose the prefix "0", only the month string lose it.

Comment: @APC, Thanks your providing,i will look through this article.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
THE_DATE DATE "mmddyyyy"
```

You will also need to modify your input data. For formats without delimiters you'll need to supply two digits for both month and day, and 4 digits for the year: `07232012` or you'll get an error for invalid month.

It's also more readable to supply delimiters. For example,

```
7/23/2012
```

is much more clear than a string of digits. The format string for such a date would be `MM/DD/YYYY`, and you don't have to specify two digits because you've delimited the date components.

Comment: Yes, Change source string is a right way, but in my scenery,i can't change the source file.